# SNAKE GAME- snake passing through barrier (PYTHON 3.8-TURTLE MODULE)

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-turtle

Tried putting it as a range but says that two operations cannot be done.

## Check for collisions with barrier

```
if (head.ycor()<200 and head.ycor()>-200 and head.xcor()<10 and head.xcor()>-10):
    time.sleep(1)
    head.goto(-70, 0)
    head.direction = "stop"
    head.clear()

# Barrier
barrier = turtle.Turtle()
barrier.shape("square")
barrier.color("yellow")
barrier.speed(0)
barrier.goto(0, 0)
barrier.shapesize(stretch_len=1, stretch_wid=20)
barrier.penup()
```

Comment: Putting as a range what? Which two operations? What are you trying to do? What is happening instead? I't not very clear from your question, please try to clarify it.

Comment: basically the snake goes through the barrier(code shown above), so in order for the snake to die, I tried two methods but none worked(I'm a beginner). The two methods are: # Check for collisions with barrier
    if head.direction(ycor(range(-200, 200) and head.direction(xcor(range(-10, 10))))):
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(-70, 0)
        head.direction = "stop"
        head.clear()                                                                                                             and the other one is shown above. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Your problem is that you are checking for the opposite condition. You have to check if `head.ycor() > 200 *OR* head.ycor() <-200` and so on. You would also need to put this in a function and call it every time you update the position. (Also the range() roes not work like you think it does)